# Docker certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: docker

I can't use `docker login` neither `docker build`, I searched about and several articles suggested [install ca-certificates](https://github.com/google/go-github/issues/1049#issuecomment-454446363), but it didn't seems to solve my problem (maybe I did the install wrong on `/etc/docker/certs.d/registry-1.docker.io:443`).

The error message is always the same:

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

About 1 ~ 2 weeks ago all were working fine.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Restart `Docker Desktop` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually comes when your machine's internal clock is not set properly.

Try this: `sudo ntpdate time.nist.gov`

If you don't have ntpdate: `sudo apt-get install ntpdate`

Comment: I run `timedatectl` command and it returned with `NTP synchronized: no`, is there the problem? @Maxime

Comment: Yeah, it's saying that your system is not synchronized with the actual time. Run what I wrote above.

Comment: I was searching, the system doesn't use `ntp`, instead it uses `chrony` and it also return `Leap status     : Not synchronised` in return of `chronyc tracking`. Any guess on what to do?

Comment: try `sudo chronyc -a makestep`

Comment: Might be useful to tell what's your distribution

Comment: CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core).

Comment: Try this: https://www.tecmint.com/synchronize-time-with-ntp-in-linux/